# Delete/Remove Material Library VX

Tags: materials, library

Anyone know how to delete/remove a "Library" under Material Library? There is a "New Library" button to add your own new library - but what if you want to remove one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to work directly on the asset blender file placed in your BlenderAssets/ directory (Pref/File Path).